# After clicking the item in an listview it has to go their respective links

Tags: java, android

Is this possible to give the links as array,we can take the link as per the respective clink of an list item,In my code i will put hardcoded my link its not looking good,what i need i want to give all the links in an array,after clicking the item in an listview,it has to open thier respective link.

```
public class SouthIndianvegrecipes  extends Activity  {

    //private Button Manual;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        ArrayList<Recipedetails1> image_details = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV1_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter1(this, image_details));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Recipedetails1 obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails1)o;
                Toast.makeText(SouthIndianvegrecipes.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName1(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } 
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<Recipedetails1> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<Recipedetails1> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails1>();

        Recipedetails1 item_details = new Recipedetails1();
        item_details.setName1("Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription1("Recipes made by raw materials");
        item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber1(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails1();
        item_details.setName1("Non-Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription1("Flesh of sweet animals");
        item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber1(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails1();
        item_details.setName1("Pickels");
        item_details.setItemDescription1("Touchable dish  by Homemade");
        item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber1(3);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails1();
        item_details.setName1("Soups");
        item_details.setItemDescription1("Startup for our food");
        item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber1(4);
        results.add(item_details);




        return results;
    }
}
```

I want to click the item in the list, it has to go their respective link for the video, but now I will put this in holder, it will show the link directly, it's not looking good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to the video. This should work:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
  Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
  Recipedetails1 obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails1)o;
  final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(o.getUrlWiki()));
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: tnx dude,but actually in my code i wil give the link in the holder,the link also showing,i dont want to show the link  my activity page

Comment: i want my link should not be display,its in holder,is this anyway to put all the links in an array and getting it my number and use it

Comment: can you tell me,how to use that one

Comment: What do you mean by "holder"?

Comment: holder in the sense for list view,we provide holder to contains image,name description and hink in an listview

Comment: item_details.setName1("Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription1("Recipes made by raw materials");
        item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber1(1);
        results.add(item_details); in my list view these 4 things coming,.image and name,description and link,that full link is showing but its not looking good,the link should be background,if i click the item it has to go the video,because i am giving link directly in my code,can you look at my code for more verification